# Requisição AJAX funciona em todos os browsers exceto o Firefox

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

Tenho tentado fazer um sistema de upload com AJAX e funciona perfeitamente no Chrome, no entanto não funciona no firefox. Usei a função `$.ajax()` do JQuery. Têm alguma sugestão do que possa ser?

Tenho um formulario normal que requer um arquivo e o AJAX faz com que um PDF Viewer apareça, do tipo:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: dados,
  success: function(data) {
    $("#mensagem").append(data);
}
})
```

E não entendo porque no firefox nao funciona.

Comment: Acesse o Firebug e veja se está dando algum outro erro no javascript que pode atrapalhar isso.

Comment: Tentei o firebug, mas mesmo assim não encontrei nada significativo. Só um NS_ERROR_FAILUTE que é um erro de AJAX comum em quem usa Firefox e um _getLoginDataFromParent: A form origin is required que possivelmente é de um PDF Viewer que estou a usar.

Comment: Vai ver que o problema nada tem a ver com o ajax, e sim com o PDF (ou seu visualizador). Experimente testar com outro conteúdo e veja se o problema permanece.

Comment: @Bacco tb acho.

Comment: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/LoginManagerContent.jsm linha 294?

Comment: Em todas as versões ou só na que você tem instalada?

Comment: Dê uma lida aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622901/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata/9622978#9622978. Acho que pode ajudar.

Comment: Depende muito de vários fatores, por favor atualize a pergunta adiconando mais informações como: Versão do Jquery, O domínio de acesso é o mesmo (CORS), versão do navegador, Dados da resposta, Encoding da resposta...

Answer (score 0):

Usa o seguinte código, onde editei "method" para "type":

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data){
                                $("#mensagem").append(data);  
                 }
});
```

Comment: [Na documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) explica que `type` é apenas um _alias_ para `method`. A única diferença é que o `method` existe apenas no jQuery 1.9.0 pra cima.